# use of normalize() in WebGL shader failing

Tags: three.js, webgl, glsles

Hi I am using normalize() function in GLSL Shader, 
If i provide something similar to vec3 v2 = normalize(vec3(1.0,2.0,0.0)) this works 
but if I use a vec3 variable it fails.
Failing GLSL code:

```
vec3 getPointOnSphereSurface(vec3 center, vec3 p2, float radius) 
{
    vec3 v = p2-center; 
    //Then calculate the length:
    float mag = length(v);
    vec3 v2 = normalize(vec3(v));       
    //Finally calculate the new vector, which is x2y2 + vxvy * (mag + distance).
    v.x = (center.x + v2.x * (mag + radius));
    v.y = (center.y + v2.y * (mag + radius));
    v.z = (center.z + v2.z * (mag + radius));       
    return v;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the code that is failing and the associated error message.

Comment: Hello Brendan, thanks for the quick revert, updated with code!

Comment: What do you mean it fails? Also note that your var `mag` will always be 1. Thats what `normalize()` does.

Comment: Also note that there is no need to wrap variables in vec3 if they are already of the type vec3. i.e. normalize(vec3(v)); should just be normalize(v); Lastly, try to make use of vector maths, the last 3 calculations can be replaced with v = center + v2 * radius;

Comment: Hello thanks for the comments, here is improved code. Now if I manually calculate value of v my results are different as compared to from above implementation, above implementation always returns v as (0.0,0.0,0.0)